# iPhoto gets stuck on finishing last import

Tags: photos.app, performance

I have this problem where iPhoto gets into a state where it won't quit, and won't let me import anything. If I try to empty the (iPhoto) trash it tells me I should "Wait until the import is finished". Only it isn't importing anything. So far my only solution to get it back to a usable state is to force quit it. Then it is good for another import, deleting the trash, or quiting.

Is there some other import process that I can kill to get iPhoto back into a useable state? I'm importing tiffs off disk.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was a permissions repair. Go to /Applications/Utilities, and open Disk Utility. Select your boot drive/partition, go to the First Aid tab, and click Verify Disk Permissions. Let it work, and see what it says. If it says you should, click Repair Permissions.